# How to use FILE * with iPhone

Tags: iphone, file

I have a file called "0.ballpoint" that all I want to do is store some coordinates with (don't really want to use Core Data because it seem a little excessive). I placed it in my project but when I try doing this:

```
if ( access("0.ballpoint", F_OK) != -1) {
    printf("file exists\n");
}
else {
    printf("doesn't exist\n");
}
```

It says it "doesn't exist". Do I need to put the full path name? And if I do what do I do when I place it on the actual iPhone/iPod Touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CoreData` is not meant for File access. There are other file API's available for iPhone.
Please go through `NSFileManager` and `NSStream` documentation.

For example, if your intention is to check if file exists at certain path,you may use
(add your file to resources)

```
NSString *filePath =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"0" ofType: @"ballpoint"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
```

Prefer not to use low level stuff (C File handles) unless you have a valid reason to do so. Paths are to be carefully chosen (as you cant make assumptions on certain path, which might cease to exist in future).

Having said that, if you prefer to work with C file handling ,

```
NSString *filePath =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"0" ofType: @"ballpoint"];
FILE *fileHandle = fopen([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"r");
```

Comment: Still trying it out, seems legit but right of the bat: "@" should be in front of the "0" and "ballpoint" and after "r" it should be a ")".

Comment: corrected, SO shud some how check sytax errors (like spell checking) :)

Comment: I got it to work but just one last thing: you should delete the bracket after "r".

Answer (score -1):

it needs to become a resource to your Application that way the file can be pulled anytime during the use of your application.

Im not too well educated in Ipod Dev, im more of a windows phone 7 developer but i know it cant access it if it is still on your computer so you need to import it into your application some how and call it with the full file path name.

Comment: So I need to test it on the iPhone (are you sure?, because they have Core Data and stuff that lets you deal with files on the iPhone simulator)? And do you know what would the full file path be for that?

Comment: if it works properly you should be able to run it right in the emulator.

Comment: you know how you navigate to a page in an application, your navigating to a file type that can be compiled down and rendered. you have to bind your file to your application and call it from your code.

Comment: Ok it works if I put whole path but do you know what whole path would be on the actual iPhone?

Comment: test that one on your Device, if it works on the emulator it should also work on the device. it simply bundles it all together and compiles it all at run time.

Comment: I can't test on my device, and I am 99% it wont work because my iPhone doesn't have a directory /users/Me/Programming/ which is what I am using in the path

Comment: Refer to Tatvamasi's Answer he is right. and like i said it has to be bundled to your application.